# How can I concat the huge pandas dataframes into one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory-leaks, data-science

I have 12 csv files with total size 8.45 GB.
I would like to read all csv files into pasdas dataframe with read_csv.

I tried using this code

```
# Example of 3 files

list = ['file-01.csv',
       'file-02.csv',
       'file-03.csv']


li = []

for filename in list:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

concat_df = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Then it showed

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 784. MiB for an array with shape (1, 102804250) and data type int64

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: How much memory does your machine have? (Or your VM, if you're running the code in a VM.)

Comment: Are you using 32-bit Python or 64-bit?  Wouldn't it be easier to combined the CSV files as text files, and then do one import?

Comment: Use the appropriate sized dtypes can you get away with using int8 instead of int64?  Maybe using bool, etc...

Comment: More context might help here: what are you going to *do* with these data frames. It's very possible that your machine cannot handle all of them in memory at once. Someone might be able to point you in the right direction if that's the case if you tell us what you're going to do with them. That being said, @ScottBoston makes a very good suggestion.

Comment: Hi everyone in this thread, I just follow the guidance from @philosofool.  It's worked for me. However, I migrated the code and files to notebook on (SageMaker, AWS) and use the big instance for this.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible, however, you will get a much more memory efficient process if you use a generator rather than appending to a list and concatenating. Creating a list and concatenating will require about twice as much memory as a generator.

Try this:

```py
#please don't use `list` as a variable name.
file_list = [
    'file-01.csv',
    'file-02.csv',
    'file-03.csv'
]

def yield_dfs(file_list):
    """generator function to yield dataframes."""
    for file_name in file_list:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
        # you may be able to reduce the memory requirements by doing some pre-processing of the dataframe here. e.g. convert strings to booleans so save memore.
        yield df

df = pd.concat(yield_dfs(file_list))
```

I didn't run that code to check for syntax errors and the specifics may vary a little depending on the paths.

If you have enough system memory for the grand DataFrame, that is pretty likely to work. However, you are talking about a very big dataframe and it depends a lot on the datatypes your are working with.

Comment: I just follow the guidance from yours. It's worked for me. However, I migrated the code and files to notebook on (SageMaker, AWS) and use the big instance for this.

Thank you anyway @philosofool.

Answer (score -2):

```
files = ['file-01.csv',
         'file-02.csv',
         'file-03.csv']

df = pd.read_csv('file-01.csv', index_col=0)

for file in files[1:]:
    df_i = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0)
    df = pd.concat((df, df_i), axis=0)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Even if this did solve the memory issue, an answer with no text at all isn't very productive. Please edit your answer to explain what your code is doing and why it solves the problem.

Comment: @Cole: Because it’s you who is putting forward an answer. If you hope for people to take it seriously, it’s useful to offer an explanation. That also helps future readers better understand the syntax and API. Kraigolas is trying to help you by offering feedback on how to improve your answer. Please consider editing your answer.